# Do we hate iblis or only his bad actions? Is it strictly forbidden to hate someone as a creature including ibliss? Is all hatred illness of heart?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, shaitan

I have read in a article  {{https://abuaminaelias.com › beware-...
Purification from the spiritual disease of hatred in Islam | Faith in Allah الإيمان بالله}} that hatred is an illness of heart. And even the non believers we don't hate them as persons but only their bad actions. And he has instructed us to love his creatures like the love for the wife even when she is christian. The love for kinship etj.... My question is:  Does this include iblis,  dajjal and the most evil creatures? In other words we don't hate iblis (on the contrary we love him) but only hate his bad actions? And we love him as a creature of Allah just like we love our Christian wife as a creature of Allah even though she commits shirk.

Answer (score 4):

There are Muslim sinners and there are Kuffar. As for the latter, if we are to follow the literal meaning of various verses of the Koran, they are to be hated not loved.

> 60:4 We have denied you, and there has appeared between us and you
>   animosity and hatred forever until you believe in Allah alone
>
> 58:22 You will not find a people who believe in Allah and the Last Day
>   having affection for those who oppose Allah and His Messenger, even if
>   they were their fathers or their sons or their brothers or their
>   kindred.

Iblis and Dajjal would definitely fall into this.

Answer (score 0):

According to me , i find ,as a person we should not hate any other person (which you already know) even not the non believers , those who are doing wrong etc but only hate their bad deeds because they can change anytime , any time Allah can guide them , so we should not hate any person but their wrong doing 
But we know (with 100% surety that shaitaan is open enemy of Allah , and he wont ever come back , instead will invove other people against Allah , so hating here is not wrong but instead right , (because you are hating him for Allah's sake)